# Handling DB connection breaks

Tags: c#, .net, database, wcf, connection

My WCF service is keeping DB connections for futher sending SQL through they. Sometimes connection become broken for various reasons. Early there was special timer that checks connections every 1 minute. But it's not so good solution of problem. Could you please advice me some way to keep connections working properly or even though reconnect as soon as possible to deliver user stable service.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Database server is Oracle. I'm connecting to databse server using devart dotConnect for Oracle.

Comment: Pooling database connections is generally not a great idea, scenario depending (which isn't exactly stated) I would tend to go with a "unit of work" connection each time. Any pooling benefits can and will come from the innards of the connection pool itself.

Comment: Post some code. That might help us to answer the question with code from your context...

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: this would already be the answer and not a comment ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to "keep" database connections. Leave the reuse and caching of database connections to the .net framework.

Just use this kind of code and dispose the connection as soon as you are finished using it:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
  //Your Code here
}
```

There is no problem in executing the code above for each call to the database. The connection information is cached and the second "new" connection to the database is very fast.

To read more about "ConnectionPooling" you might read this [MSDN Articel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).

Edit:

If you use pooling the connection is not really close but put back to the pool. The initial "handshake" between the client and the database is only done once per connection on the pool.

The component you are using supports the connection pooling as well:

[Read1](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17435&sid=eb52bcd088f006a7fed398471c3669f4)
[Read 2](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionString.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is a lot of intensively sending requests for DBs, so it's getting much faster with keeping all db connections open.

Comment: I don't think so. I've done a transaction system that did millions of database calls during a day and there was no big performance hit. Sharing a connection over more that one Unit of Work can be very dangerous and error prone.

Comment: And did you measure the performance for let's say 100'000 database requests with sharing the connection and without?

Comment: @kseen - All we know is your having a problem, this answer is our suggestion, and to be frank is the correct way to handle it.  So you have a choice, make sure the connection is never broken, or change the method you use to connect to the database.

Comment: @YvesM. Is connection opens every time when code like you shown is executed with Connection Pooling?

Comment: @kseen: if you use pooling the connection is not really close but put back to the pool. The initial "handshake" between the client and the database is only done once per connection on the pool.

Comment: @YvesM. Oh that's great! And can I get some information about your transaction system that handling millions calls?

Comment: But wrong. every time a conenction is ataken out of the pool, a reset sequence is executed to test the connection is still valid and to reset any / all fragments still left over from the old connection. Clearly visible in the trace of all sql running.

Comment: That said, the overhead normally is neglegible comapred to the rurnning sql statements.

Comment: @YvesM. Another my subquestion is how can I prepare and put connections to pool when WCF service is starting up?

Comment: @YvesM.: this is done automatically when you do new SqlConenction(...) for the first time for each unique connection string.

Comment: @TomTom: you are right. but the reset sequence is not as heavy asthe first initialization where all the authentication and session stuff is done.

Comment: I know - but reusing a known connection is stll faster. We optimized it that way with a system doing like a couple of tens of thousands connections per second.

Comment: @kseen: the performance has to be maintained over the whole stack of the application to be able to provide a system that can deliver millions of transactions per day. This starts be streamlining the output to only those fields that are really nessecessary down to the optimal network binding on the wcf services.

Comment: @YvesM. But if I want setup connections and put it into pool at initialization stage? How can I get it?

Comment: @TomTom Ok, keeping connections always alive is better idea than connetion pooling. But the major question is how can we get them always open? How can we recognise break connection as fast as possible?

Comment: You don't. You have code to handle connection breaking down with a retry logic that re-establishes the connection and retries.

Comment: @TomTom Ok, thanks! However how can I be sure that all connections in pool are alive? May I iterate over connections in pool and check they state like your said in previous comment?

Comment: You dont. I take one, submit sql, whnen i get the appropriate exception i discard it take the enxt and retry.

Comment: @TomTom Do you keep multiple connections to one database server or just one?

Comment: Depends. I ahve an app here that currently has about 130 open and will soon be changed to have around 250 open. Totally depends on what the application needs.

Comment: @TomTom May I somehow talk with you using IMs or something like that? I don't want to get a long comment's talkings here.